# Firebase onAuthStateChanged not firing on login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I got firebase authentication to work to a point where I can create users, and log them in and out.

I need to make sure to do a few more things:

- detect login/logout state change and do some actions based on this
- get user ID on login so I can push them to the firebase DB

Unfortunately somehow my onAuthStateChanged method does not seem to be working. Also I'm not able to get user.uid - I'm getting an error that user is not defined. Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Firebase Auth Test</title>

    <!-- Firebase JavaScript Link -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- JQuery -->


    <!-- ================================================================================== -->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Initialize Firebase
            var config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyC0rCQY0jzdWe5AhcQpvIuKMr9XbnRWDsk",
                authDomain: "project1-e7460.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://project1-e7460.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "project1-e7460",
                storageBucket: "project1-e7460.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "87795057294"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
            // Get a reference to the database service
            var database = firebase.database();
            $("#signup").on("click", function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                var email = $("#email").val().trim();
                var password = $("#pass").val().trim();
                console.log('trying to create!');
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    // ...
                });

            });

            $("#refset").on("click", function () {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('ref set!');
                firebase.database().ref().set({
                    username: "name",
                    email: "email"
                });
            });

            $("#login").on("click", function () {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var email = $("#email").val().trim();
                    var password = $("#pass").val().trim();
                    console.log('trying to log in!');
                    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
                        // Handle Errors here.
                        var errorCode = error.code;
                        var errorMessage = error.message;
                        // ...
                    }).then(function(user) {
                        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                    });
            });


        $("#logout").on("click", function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('trying Sign out in!');
            firebase.auth().signOut().then(function () {
                console.log('signed out!');
                // Sign-out successful.
            }).catch(function (error) {
                // An error happened.
            });
        });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if (user) {
                console.log('signed in!');
                // User is signed in.
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                console.log('not signed in');
            }
        });


        });
    </script>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input id="email" placeholder="email" type="email">
    <input id="pass" placeholder="pass" type="password">
    <button id="signup" type="submit">Signup</button>
    <button id="login" type="submit">Log in</button>
    <button id="logout" type="submit">Log Out</button>
    <button id="refset" type="submit">Refset</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: actually users are being created & signed in, but I still get this error for each user creation or signin: Failed to load https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getAccountInfo?key=AIzaSyC0rCQY0jzdWe5AhcQpvIuKMr9XbnRWDsk: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
auth/network-request-failed
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to overwrite the user from the observer function, so change it to this (so you'll get the event when the user signs in inside the if and the uid for db storage):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    //var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
        console.log('signed in!');
        console.log(user.uid);
        // User is signed in, call db storage function here
    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        console.log('not signed in');
    }
});
```